# How to have text with multiple colours in java?

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, colors, jlabel

I'm trying to make a spellchecker, and the result should be a window with the incorrectly spelt words highlighted. The text is stored in an array (currently) and the id of the missing words is sorted in another. How would I go about doing this?

**EDIT:** This is what I have so far, yet it doesn't seem to work.

```
int l = 0;
String txtstring = "<html>";
for(int i = 0; i<textArray.length ; i++){
    if(placement[l].equals(i)){
        l++;
        txtstring = txtstring + "<font color = red>" + textArray[i] + "</font>" + " ";
     } else {
        txtstring = txtstring + textArray[i] + " ";
    }
}
txtstring = txtstring + "</html>";
```

Comment: Probably by writing code.  You have written code before, right?

Comment: wow, thanks for that enlightening response.

Comment: It’s not meant to be dismissive.  How can I begin to address your question, without knowing if you even know the basics of Swing?  In fact, I don’t even know for sure you want to display your text in Swing;  I am only guessing that based on the presence of a `jlabel` tag.  You need to describe the current state of your program, and what you’ve tried so far, if only to let us know what your current level of experience is.

Comment: ohh, right. my bad. i have used swing before, but at a very basic level. also added the code i have managed to hash together, which at least gets it into the frame but doesn't colour it.

Comment: You start out by matching your words against `placement[0]`, and only if `placement[0]` is matched do you then check subsequent words for a match against `placement[1]`.  This means “quick broun fawx” would result in zero red words, if `placement` is `{ "qwik", "broun", "fawx" }`.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: earlier in the code, `placement` was created by a method that searched through the initial text submitted, so for "the wizzard eatd my stuf" `placement` would contain `{"1", "2", "4"}` in that order.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  You’re comparing `placement` elements to `i`, not to strings.  What is the type of `placement`?

Comment: okay, so it's now `Integer.parseInt(placement)` and that solves it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy-pasting last edit made by OP:

Changing

```
if(placement[l].equals(i)){
```

for

```
if(Integer.parseInt(placement[l])==i){
```

did the trick, so it ends up like this:

```
int l = 0;
String txtstring = "<html>";
for(int i = 0; i<textArray.length ; i++){
    if(Integer.parseInt(placement[l])==i){
        l++;
        txtstring = txtstring + "<font color = red>" + textArray[i] + "</font>" + " ";
     } else {
        txtstring = txtstring + textArray[i] + " ";
    }
}
txtstring = txtstring + "</html>";
```